# AngularJS $http scope issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a bootstrap dialog box where the user can enter shipping tracking number. 2 buttons - one to cancel and one to ship. A controller is tied to this. Upon success I want to change the status of that order (in an ng-repeated list) to "shipped". But it's not working. What am I doing wrong here?

Controller with dialog sub controller:

```
function ManageOrderCtrl($scope, $http, $dialog) {

  // Setup some dialog options for shipping popup
  var dialogOptions = {
    controller: 'ShipOrderCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/partials/order/_ship.html'
  };

  // Shipping action - launches popup for tracking #
  $scope.shipOrder = function(order){
      var itemToEdit = order;
     $dialog.dialog(angular.extend(dialogOptions, {
        resolve: {
          order: angular.copy(itemToEdit)
        }
      }
    ))
    .open()
     .then(function(result) {
      if(result) {
       angular.copy(result, itemToEdit);
       }
       itemToEdit = undefined;
     })
  };
}

// Shipping controller (injected in ship dialog)
function ShipOrderCtrl($scope, $http, order, dialog){
  $scope.order = order;

  // Called when they click "mark as shipped" on dialog
  $scope.ship = function() {

    dialog.close($scope.order);

     //This works fine from here
     //$scope.order.status = 'shipped';

    $http.put('api/order/ship/' + $scope.order._id, { 
      tracking: $scope.order.tracking 
    })
    .then(function(response) {

      // This doesn't work
      $scope.order.status = 'shipped';
    });
  };
  // Cancel the dialog
  $scope.close = function(){
    dialog.close(undefined);
  }; 
}
```

View:

```
<div ng-conroller="ManageOrderCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="order in orders">
     <span class="status">{{ order.status }}</span>
     <a href="#"  ng-click="shipOrder(order)"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "This doesn't work". Whether the `then` block is called or not ? or some other errors ? The code seems to be correct!

Comment: Well it doesn't update the status on my list. I have a similar piece of code to cancel an order which works - I suspect it has to do with the extra bit of the dialog but since I can mark it as shipped earlier on (where commented out) it seems all valid. Weird

Comment: I've updated my post with more code

Comment: i'm not sure if this could work, but can u give it a try,
`$scope.$apply(function() {
    
$scope.order.status = 'shipped';

  });`

Comment: Nope - I get an error: $digest already in progress

Comment: can u verify if the scope inside the then block is same as the one that is coming outside the else block, with the help of the id attribute in it.

Comment: Ok now I am totally confused. I got it working by adding 'backdropFade: true,' just before 'resolve' - which makes zero sense.

Comment: Ok - tested in other browsers, cleared cache and tried other dialog options such as backdropClick, etc.. doesn't work. But adding backdropFade: true makes it work in all browsers. What?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - it's a bug in Angular Bootstrap dialog - fixed in 0.2.0 - I was using 0.1.0